# Select unique values from the same column in two tables

Tags: mysql, sql, duplicates, unique

I'm just playing with SQL and want to achieve the following result
I have the following tables:

```
TABLE_1   ID   NAME
          1    CAR
          2    ANIMAL
          5    ROCK

TABLE_2   ID   NAME
          1    GRASS
          2    ROCKET
          3    STONE
          4    DOG
```

I want my query to return unique ID values from both tables:

```
ID
3
4
5
```

I have tried using DISTINCT and FULL OUTER JOINS, but without success.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `UNION ALL` , group it and use the `HAVING` clause :

```
SELECT ID FROM (
    SELECT ID FROM Table_1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT ID FROM Table_2)
GROUP BY ID
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
```

Comment: Even though my answer works as requested, this one costs less (and also repeats less code), therefore it probably is the best answer. (+1)

Comment: Well if it give you error `1248 - Every derived table must have its own alias` then solve it by adding  alias like `SELECT ID FROM (
    SELECT ID FROM Table_1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT ID FROM Table_2) AS my_alias
GROUP BY ID
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1`

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT ID
FROM (
  SELECT ID
  FROM TABLE_1

  UNION ALL

  SELECT ID
  FROM TABLE_2) AS t
GROUP BY ID
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT id FROM table_1 WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM table_2)
UNION
SELECT id FROM table_2 WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM table_1)
```

Comment: Why? It is correct. There are no duplicates, because id is NOT IN.

Comment: Unfortunately it returns 1, 3, 4, 5

Comment: No it doesn't. It returns 3, 4, 5.

Comment: I was searching to get 1,2,3,4,5 with no dublicate, I had to remove the condition but you put me in good way. Thx

Answer (score 2):

Try this;)

```
SELECT ID
FROM(
  SELECT DISTINCT ID FROM TABLE1
  UNION ALL
  SELECT DISTINCT ID FROM TABLE2
) T
GROUP BY ID
HAVING COUNT(ID) = 1
```

[SQLFiddle DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bdba6/6)

Answer (score 0):

Construct the intersection manually using UNION. It's easy if you have some unique field in both tables, e.g. ID:

```
SELECT id FROM Table 1
WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM Table 2)

UNION

SELECT id FROM Table 2
WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM Table 1)
```

Answer (score -2):

```
SELECT table_1.id
FROM   table_1
WHERE  table_1.id NOT IN (SELECT table_2.id FROM table_2)
UNION
SELECT table_2.id
FROM   table_2
WHERE  table_2.id NOT IN (SELECT table_1.id FROM table_1)
```

Comment: No need to select **4** times .